# Why would it be logical to call clearance delivery prior to CTAF during an instrument approach?

Tags: radio-communications, instrument-procedures

I am quoting this directly from [the FAA's Instrument Procedures Handbook publication](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/media/FAA-H-8083-16B_Chapter_4.pdf#page=11).

> "The communication strip provided near the top of FAA approach charts gives flight crews the frequencies that they can expect to be assigned
>   during the approach. The frequencies are listed in the logical order
>   of use from arrival to touchdown."

Here is the communications strip from the plate in the prior page:
[image: Comm Strip]

Never once have I been trained to contact clearance delivery prior to CTAF during the execution of an instrument approach procedure, much less any time other than when I am trying to get my initial IFR clearance.

Why is this listed before the CTAF?  Would a tower or ground frequency not be more appropriate and would it not be more appropriate to have it in logical order as the last frequency, not the second-to-last?

Comment: Note that it is an untowered airport, so you'll have to close your flight plan—it might still make sense to ask why it is listed before CTAF though (in the duplicate it is last).

Comment: The other question is asking purely about the existence of clearance delivery on the approach plate.  A portion of my question was indeed a duplicate, so those parts have been removed and now the question only reflects matters of the *order* of appearance rather than the *reason* for appearance.